# Flash caches a JSON response when we never want it to

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, json, caching

We have a game built in Actionscript 3, but for some users when they load the game it's loading the cached version of their saved game (JSON string) instead of getting the latest one from the server. We've implemented a random string at the end of the request URL, and I've also added headers for pragma and cache-control to the request. I'm not sure if adding those headers will make a difference though.

Is there anything else we can do to fix this? Will adding those headers help? Is there any documentation about how different browsers would handle this?

It's not a problem we can test so we're pretty much stabbing in the dark until users stop emailing us about it.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using SharedObjects to store their saves locally?

Comment: No, we use shared object to build a queue of saves so that they submit in a controlled order, but we load the saves off a server with URLRequest.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the random query-string has always worked for me. Perhaps you could try and use a debug proxy to see what's going on behind the scenes. I swear by [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/), but I also hear good things about [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).

Comment: wireshark is also an alternative or just plain firebug will do the trick as well

Answer (score 0):

Two things you could try:

- Use POST request
- Add a random string (unix time stamp or something similar) at the end of you URL that is totally ignored by your server: `foo/bar.json?foo=bar&dc=1315486845135`

Comment: We already do both of these things, but it looks like the random string business is the main solution so hopefully this will solve the issue.